# Show child categories without GW Code Categories

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

I'm trying to just show child categories of a specific parent and have used GW Code Categories in the past.

I would just pass the category ID to GW Code and voila!

Now that GW Code Categories is not supported in the latest version of EE (5.3.2), how can I replicate the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options depending on what actually you are doing...

1. Use a fork of GWCode updated for EE5 - [here](https://github.com/t1mwillis/GWCode-EE3-EE4-EE5)
2. Use [category construct](https://buzzingpixel.com/software/category-construct/documentation/template-tags) - an add-on with similar abilities
3. Use [URL-Helper](https://github.com/litzinger/URL-Helper) - only works on segments but does the job in many cases: can map slugs to categories based on name or category ID.

HTH

> PS - To get better answers it helps if you can add information about
> what version of EE you are using (and sometimes what version of
> php)... thanks!

Comment: Thank you! The fork of GWCode works great. Didn't know that existed. And you are absolutely right. I should have provided the version of EE. Thanks again!